# How to pass image as url into arraylist using picaso library instead of drawable resource?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, drawable, custom-lists

**arr_title,arr_description,arr_img are the array list**

```
                arr_title.add(title);
                arr_description.add(description);
                arr_img.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

arr_img , here takes a static image which is working fine . But , how to get it done dynamically from an image url , so that I get to fetch image from url and pass it into this arr_img , than just drawable image .

I tried , using Picaso library , but I did not understand , how to use it in place of drawable ?

**This is my ArrayAdapter**

class MyClass extends ArrayAdapter
    {

```
    public MyClass(Context context, int resource, ArrayList img,ArrayList txt,ArrayList img_res) 
    {
        super(context, resource,img);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inf=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inf.inflate(R.layout.post_list_design,null);

        t1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_list_design);
        t1.setText(arr_title.get(position).toString());

        t2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc_list_design);
        t2.setText(arr_description.get(position).toString());

        i3=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_logo);
        i3.setImageResource((Integer)arr_img.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Its better store image URL in one String and pass the string in Load methods instead of direct passing URL. It works. For me it is working Great.

```
final ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("Image Url").into(image);
```

Comment: For me its working perfectly. What is error or exception you are getting?

Comment: Required a bit modification from the arraylist perspective . Solved

Comment: That's great . happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Picasso.with(context)
  .load(arr_img.get(position))
   .resize(100, 100)
   .centerCrop()
   .into(i3);
```

Try this!

Comment: is url stored in arr_img.get(position)?

Comment: Firstly , because , I am loading the images from the server , it takes very long to respond and then , I get an empty screen without listview

Comment: the title and description isn't displaying too?

Comment: title and description are visible alone . But , when I get the imageview along them , then these text contents dont work and the entire listview disappears

Comment: can you send the url?

Comment: Its on my local server

Comment: Change your imageview height and width from wrap_content, and give a hardcoded value

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it, Lets suppose this is `url` list

```
static final String BASE = "http://i.imgur.com/";
static final String EXT = ".jpg";
static final String[] URLS = {
  BASE + "CqmBjo5" + EXT, BASE + "zkaAooq" + EXT, BASE + "0gqnEaY" + EXT,
  BASE + "9gbQ7YR" + EXT, BASE + "aFhEEby" + EXT, BASE + "0E2tgV7" + EXT,
  BASE + "P5JLfjk" + EXT, BASE + "nz67a4F" + EXT, BASE + "dFH34N5" + EXT,
  BASE + "FI49ftb" + EXT, BASE + "DvpvklR" + EXT, BASE + "DNKnbG8" + EXT,
  BASE + "yAdbrLp" + EXT, BASE + "55w5Km7" + EXT, BASE + "NIwNTMR" + EXT,
  BASE + "DAl0KB8" + EXT, BASE + "xZLIYFV" + EXT, BASE + "HvTyeh3" + EXT,
  BASE + "Ig9oHCM" + EXT, BASE + "7GUv9qa" + EXT, BASE + "i5vXmXp" + EXT,
  BASE + "glyvuXg" + EXT, BASE + "u6JF6JZ" + EXT, BASE + "ExwR7ap" + EXT,
  BASE + "Q54zMKT" + EXT, BASE + "9t6hLbm" + EXT, BASE + "F8n3Ic6" + EXT,
  BASE + "P5ZRSvT" + EXT, BASE + "jbemFzr" + EXT, BASE + "8B7haIK" + EXT,
  BASE + "aSeTYQr" + EXT, BASE + "OKvWoTh" + EXT, BASE + "zD3gT4Z" + EXT,
  BASE + "z77CaIt" + EXT,
};
```

and in your adapter

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater inf=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView=inf.inflate(R.layout.post_list_design,null);

    t1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_list_design);
    t1.setText(arr_title.get(position).toString());

    t2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc_list_design);
    t2.setText(arr_description.get(position).toString());

    // Get the image URL for the current position.
    String url = getItem(position);

    i3=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_logo);


   Picasso.with(context)
        .load(url) 
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) 
        .error(R.drawable.error) 
        .fit() 
        .tag(context) 
        .into(i3);


    return convertView;
}

}
```

This is pretty basic example of course you would have to pass the List of images to your adapter first.

Hope it helps

you can check [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/tree/master/picasso-sample) the detailed example

Comment: Instead of using the string url array , can I not pass the urls into arraylist ?

Comment: Yes . Is there any other solution ? or a better one to fetch from url to save loading time ?

Answer (score 1):

better to use getter setter method in array list.
then image is set as a string.

and in adapter to load every URL into imageview like...

```
Picasso.with(mFragment.getActivity()).load(mCardList.get(i).getProfilePictureFiles().get(0).getUrl()).into(image).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```